# Integration to find general solution of free particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, integration

I was attempting problems in Griffiths Intro to QM when I came across the following:

> A free particle has the initial wavefunction:
>   $$\Psi(x, 0) = Ae^{-ax^2} \, .$$
>   Find $\Psi(x, t)$.

I normalised the initial wavefunction and found $\phi(k)$, and I managed to get the following equation for $\Psi(x, t)$:

$$\Psi(x, t)
= \frac{1}{(2\pi a)^\frac{1}{4}} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \exp\left[ikx - k^2 \left( \frac{1}{2a} + \frac{\hbar t}{2m} \right) \right] \frac{dk}{2\pi} \, .$$

I got stuck after that so I looked at the answer booklet provided and my luck failed me. The answer went from the integral I provided immediately to the final result with no intermediate steps.

Any help would be much appreciated. It looks like it requires changing the integral to be with respect to x.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this integral. Do you know contour integration? Also, this post focuses specifically on how to do an integral, so it should probably be on the math site. However, since there are a bajillion posts on the internet explaining how to do this sort of integral, I'd hesitate to migrate this question there. Did you try Googling "Gaussian integral" or something like that?

Comment: @DanielSank: Wouldn't it be considered as _homework_ question?

Comment: @user36790 Perhaps, but I always consider all other available close reasons *before* the homework one for two reasons. First, the homework close reason is confusing [as I've described in the meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7162/should-we-rename-the-homework-policy). Second, the other close reasons give the OP a better idea of how to improve than does the homework one.

Comment: @DanielSank I'm sorry if I broke any rules, I attempted the question and was stuck at a specific portion. I managed to identify the Gaussian integral form but it was the switch from dk to dx which I can't get through.

Comment: My comment was meant to help you understand the resources available to you and how they're best used. The math stack exchange site is really great for questions like this. Our policy is roughly that questions like this, which specifically ask a purely math question, are off topic. It's good to know that because in the future you may see questions like this getting closed. I just wanted you to understand *why* and also to understand your alternatives (i.e. the math site).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral can be computed independent of $x$, in fact, it must, because $x$ must remain after the integration, otherwise, $\Psi(x,t)$ would no longer be a function of $x$.  Instead, you are integrating out the variable $k$.

Anyway, you can try writing down the argument for the exponential, and then completing the square.  Then you'll have something like $$e^{-C(k+A)^2 + B}$$in which case, $e^B$ can be factored out, and you can do a substitution $$u = k+A$$ $$du = dk$$ to make it a simple Gaussian integral.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The reason I got stuck was because the final answer looked like a result obtained for a Gaussian integral with respect to x, and since x and k were independent I didn't know what to do. I completed the square once to obtain the expression in my question, but I didn't think to complete the square AGAIN even though it held the same form as my first expression. I must be blind. Thank you so much for the help, was stuck at this for a long time.

Comment: You're welcome.  The whole idea of Fourier Transforms is to find the k spectrum (wavenumber) of some arbitrary function of x, and back.  Think of the arbitrary function as being made up of a continuous distribution of sinusoidal functions of different k values, and you're trying to find the relative weights of the decompositions as a continuous function of k.  Then to get the time depending wavefunction, you tack on an e^(-iE(k)t/h_bar) to each decomposition, where E is a function of k, just like you would in a discrete case.

Comment: If $A$ is imaginary, this is not a simple substitution but a shift of contour which is only allowed if no poles are encountered during the shift.